# How Segwit makes transactions smaller? What about the witness?

Tags: segregated-witness

I have seen similar questions without a clear answer. So, how does Segregated Witness make transactions smaller? I understand it removes data from the transaction hash and solves malleability ... But it adds a field called "witness", so, how does this save space?

Also (this is related and helps understand the question), how is block size [calculated](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-size.html)? Does it include the witness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SegWit doesn't save space, per se.

What it does do is:

1. From the perspective of a non-upgraded node, it makes transactions *seem* smaller. The witness part is not recognized or considered by pre-fork nodes, so more of them can fit in a block.
2. From the perspective of an upgraded node, the block size is calculated differently. Less weight is assigned to witness data than to non-witness data. So for the purpose of the calculation, a SegWit transaction is considered lighter than a non-SegWit transaction. So more of them are allowed per block - but the physical data size of the block increases as a result.

SegWit was to be introduced anyway because it solves malleability etc. But it also offered an opportunity to increase the block size limit (to allow more transactions) without requiring a hard fork, and this opportunity was seized, resulting in the feature described above.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer, you write "Less weight is assigned to witness data than to non-witness data", this is kind of confusing, can you elaborate? how is block size calculated? I will update the question to include this.

Comment: Blocks are no longer limited by size in bytes, rather they are limited by the number of "weight units" which are an arbitrary unit based upon bytes. Each byte of a transaction that is not witness data (so everything that a non-segwit node would see) is worth 4 weight units. Every byte of witness data is worth 1 weight unit. Blocks are limited to 4000000 weight units, which, if full of non-segwit transactions, is 1 MB.